# Call stored procedure from oracle package

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my sql

```
DECLARE
out_arg1 VARCHAR(30);
out_arg2 VARCHAR(30);
out_arg3 NUMERIC;
BEGIN
call MYPACKAGE.MyProcedure('A1405','3C',NULL,NULL,out_arg1 ,out_arg2 ,out_arg3 ,NULL);
dbms_output.put_line('Result 1: ' || out_arg1 );
dbms_output.put_line('Result 2: ' || out_arg2 );
dbms_output.put_line('Result 3: ' || out_arg3 );
END;
```

After executing I have this exception

> Encountered the symbol "MYPACKAGE" when expecting one of the
>   following...

I'm 100% sure that I have this package and I have this stored procedure in it. Furthermore, I have a code that calls this procedure and everything works fine until I try to call it manually.

Could you please tell me what am I missing ?

Comment: you don't need a specific " call" keyword to call a procedure from your package, a direct,  pkg_name.procedure name would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try follwing:

```
DECLARE
out_arg1 VARCHAR(30);
out_arg2 VARCHAR(30);
out_arg3 NUMERIC;
BEGIN
MYPACKAGE.MyProcedure('A1405','3C',NULL,NULL,out_arg1 ,out_arg2 ,out_arg3 ,NULL);
dbms_output.put_line('Result 1: ' || out_arg1 );
dbms_output.put_line('Result 2: ' || out_arg2 );
dbms_output.put_line('Result 3: ' || out_arg3 );
END;
```